# SfNumericTextBox not updating the bound property when moving initial date in SfCalendar

Tags: xamarin.forms, syncfusion, syncfusion-calendar

Using SfCalendar and SfNumericTextBox version 19.2.0.62
Xamarin Forms 5.0.0.2401

I have a view in Xamarin Forms 5.0 that has an SfNumericTextBox bound to a nullable int and has AllowNulls = True

We also have an SfCalendar control bound to a DateTime field in the same ViewModel

1. Initial View and ViewModel loads
2. Edit value in Numeric Text box.ViewModel property does not get
   changed
3. Tap a different date in the calendar control. Bound Current date
   property is updated but bound nullable int does not get updated
4. Tap another date in the calendar control. Bound Current date
   property is updated AND now the nullable into property gets updated.

We need the binding of the numeric textbox to update at step 3 when the first Date is changed.

It does update when the keyboard is dismissed but I really need it to happen on change or LostFocus

Comment: I knew it wasn't going to be a ViewModel issues so I didn't see much point  in including that code and there was no code in the View

Answer (score 0):

I also asked the question on the Syncfusion forum, where SF answered it.

I needed to update the `ValueChangeMode` on the TextBox to `OnKeyFocus`

https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/182594/sfnumerictextbox-not-updating-the-bound-property-when-moving-initial-date-in-sfcalendar?reply=SFqE8j